# Searching AFINN-165 json by score

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a emotion-adjusted Youtube search engine which maps a score (read from webcam images by Microsoft Azure Emotion API) to a few words selected in the AFINN-165 list, and then peforms a Youtube search.

The code is written in Node & Express (returns the answer by GET request).

I'm trying to search the JSON by value of a word. Example; When I give the function (5) it would return all words that have a score of five.
The JSON is structured like this:

```
var data = {
 word: score,
 word: score,
 word: score,
};
```

Which I wrap in an array below

```
function getWordsByScore() {
  var afinnKeys = Object.keys(afinn);
  var afinnArray = [afinn]
  console.log(afinnKeys.length);

 for (var i = 0; i < afinnKeys.length; i++) {
  var word = String(afinnKeys[i]);
  return(afinnArray[0].word);
 }
}
```

Somehow I just can't get it to work. I try to get the actual 'word' by creating an array of keys in AfinnKeys. But feeding this word by a forloop to the afinnArray[0] just gives undefined as a return.

I hope someone could help me out. Have been stuck on this for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting undefined is because your for loop runs once and then returns immediately.

The value it tries to return is `afinnArray[0].word` which looks for the property `word` on the `afinnArray[0]` object when you may have meant to do `afinnArray[0][word]` which uses the string variable `word` as the property name.

You also never pass the score to the function so as it is it won't be based on the score.

All you really need to do is to compare the score passed in to the function to the score in the afinn object by using the word from the `word` variable obtained your for loop as the key (and it's already a string so there's no need to cast it to one). Then, if the scores match, push the word to a new array. Once the for loop completes, return the new array.

```js
var afinn = {
 a: 1,
 b: 1,
 c: 0,
 d: 0,
 e: 2,
 f: 2
};

function getWordsByScore(score) {
  var afinnKeys = Object.keys(afinn);
  var afinnArray = []

  for (var i = 0; i < afinnKeys.length; i++) {
    var word = afinnKeys[i];
    if(afinn[word] == score){
      afinnArray.push(word)
    }
  }
  return afinnArray
}

console.log(getWordsByScore(1))
```

Or as another commenter suggested, use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Definitely helped me out right there! Thanks. I was still testing the function, so I mostly do that by just hard-coding the score as soon as I get the mechanism running hence why the function didn't take a score parameter yet. But you truly gave a constructive & all-including answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help you?

```
var score = 3;
var data = {
 'firstword': 1,
 'secondword': 2,
 'thirdword': 3,
 'forthword': 3
};

var result = Object.keys(data).filter(function (key) {
  return data[key] === score
});

console.log(result);
```